# Conexão dbf local funciona mas falha quando remota

Tags: asp.net, conexão, dbase

Eu tenho o código:

```
string DbfConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\DUMP\sgc\D; Extended Properties=dBASE IV;";
```

Funciona perfeitamente no meu note, mas quando coloco a aplicação no cliente apresenta a mensagem:

> C:\DUMP\sgc\D' não é um caminho válido. Certifique-se de que o nome do
>   caminho esteja escrito corretamente e que você esteja conectado ao
>   servidor no qual o arquivo reside.

Comment: Claudio, pelo erro você não tem um banco de dados dBase disponível do caminho em questão. Você precisa ou mover / criar um banco de dados nesse caminho ou alterar sua aplicação para apontar para o caminho do banco no servidor.

Comment: Anthony, a estrutura de diretorios e banco de dados é igual tanto no note quanto no servidor do cliente. Obrigado pelo interesse.

Comment: Tentei a solução em

Comment: Tentei a solução em  http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/resolving-error-when-publishing-workbook-with-file-datasource?lang=pt-br. Também não funcionou.